# I want to make a button with an icon of the triangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have wanted to make a button with an icon of the triangle like the iBooks app style. 
[image: I want make this button (in iBooks app)]

When the button is pressed, a list screen is displayed. 
Then you select a list, statement of the button will be the selected text and an icon of the triangle. The icon is always right side.

```
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGFloat titleWidth = self.button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat imageWidth = self.button.imageView.bounds.size.width;
// Title is left Image is right
self.button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -imageWidth, 0, imageWidth);
self.button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, titleWidth, 0, -titleWidth);
```

So I tried to make a sample app.

https://github.com/kawai-hiroyuki/LikeIBooksDropDownMenu

However, the position of the icon will deviate absolutely. 
How will I do to be installed on the right side is always the icon.

Comment: customButton -with image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this very easily by subclassing UIButton and overriding `setTitle:forState:` to add a space then a down arrow in unicode. Just set the title and the arrow is automatically added at the right font. It also handles extremely long names as "Extremely l... name ▼"

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    title = [title stringByAppendingString:@" \u25BE"]; //Unicode - Small down arrow
    [super setTitle:title forState:state];
    [self sizeToFit];
}
```

If you want an example or or just a complete subclass that is also a drop down menu I'd suggest [this](https://github.com/kevinrandrup/CWDropDownMenu).
Disclaimer: I made it.

Comment: I think this solution is good. But I also think looks is not same.

Comment: I suspect @"\u25BE" would be the unicode triangle in the picture above. (Personally I like the bigger one)

Answer (score 1):

You could draw this with a `UIBezierPath`, put this in your `drawRect` method of your `UIButton` subclass

```
static const float kTriangleHeight = 8.0f;
static const float kTriangleWidth = 8.0f;

UIBezierPath *trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - kTriangleWidth - 3.0f, (self.frame.size.height / 2) - kTriangleHeight / 2)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - kTriangleWidth - 3.0f, (self.frame.size.height / 2) + kTriangleHeight / 2)];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - 3.0f, self.frame.size.height / 2)];
[trianglePath closePath];
[[UIColor blueColor] set];
[trianglePath fill];
```

Comment: I tried your code. but I could not eliminate error at "lineToPoint".

Comment: Isn't it `addLineToPoint`? The `lineToPoint` is a `NSBezierPath` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Rob, I copied this code from a Cocoa project but missed out on changing these lines. I edited my answer

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UIBezierPath' declares the selector 'lineToPoint:'